# How can I tile boxes in 2x2 orientation inside of a flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I created a container (non-flex) and divided it into an upper half with 4 rows of fixed-height list items, and the bottom half of the box to fill whatever space was left over. Inside that bottom box, my intention is to style 4 child boxes to fit 2x2. I could probably separate them into 2 row containers each with 2 boxes and that would work but I think it can be done without adding any elements.

**I can't figure out how to style the 4 boxes in 2x2 orientation within the lower flexbox, since it has no fixed height, meaning inner elements are difficult to define the height for.** How can I do this with flexbox?

```css
/* Menu / Primary Styles */

#Menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 3in;
  background-color: green;
}
#Menu .item {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  height: 0.3in;
  background-color: #ff4343;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 0 0.032in;
  border-color: #ff6c6c;
}
#Menu .item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ff5454;
}
#Menu .bottom {
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#Menu .bottom .box {
  flex: 1;
  /* width:50%; */
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
#Menu .bottom .box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<div id="Menu">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div id="" class="box">1</div>
    <div id="" class="box">2</div>
    <div id="" class="box">3</div>
    <div id="" class="box">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Target result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example :

```css
#Menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 3in;
  background-color: green;
}
#Menu .item {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  height: 0.3in;
  background-color: #ff4343;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 0 0.032in;
  border-color: #ff6c6c;
}
#Menu .item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ff5454;
}
#Menu .bottom {
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.box {
  flex: 1;
    flex-basis:50%;
   /*width:50%;*/
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.bottom div:first-child, .bottom div:last-child
{
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<div id="Menu">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div id="" class="box">1</div>
    <div id="" class="box">2</div>
    <div id="" class="box">3</div>
    <div id="" class="box">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In `.box` added `flex-basis:50%` (This defines the default size of an element before the remaining space is distributed. The main-size value makes it match the width or height, depending on which is relevant based on the flex-direction.). But I have to change about set `background-color` for `.box`

Answer (score 0):

Change your *bottom box* css rules as follows. I hope this will work for you

```
 #Menu .bottom .box {
      /*flex: 1;*/
      width:50%;
      background-color: #f3f3f3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is `flex: 1` and absence of width for the `box`. The solution is below, not sure about the grey backgrounds:

```css
/* Menu / Primary Styles */

#Menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 3in;
  background-color: green;
}
#Menu .item {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  height: 0.3in;
  background-color: #ff4343;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 0 0.032in;
  border-color: #ff6c6c;
}
#Menu .item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ff5454;
}
#Menu .bottom {
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#Menu .bottom .box {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  width: 50%;
}
#Menu .bottom .box:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}
```

```html
<div id="Menu">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div id="" class="box">1</div>
    <div id="" class="box">2</div>
    <div id="" class="box">3</div>
    <div id="" class="box">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will help you out. It might not be the size you want but its a 2x2 flexbox. Maybe you could change the css to fit it as you want it.

```css
.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
}
.grid-item {
  flex: 1 1 calc(100% - 50px);
  background: #F90;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #F00;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    A1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    B1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    A2
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    B2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work with my question because with my container, there can be no fixed height - the container itself is a flexbox, filling remaining space so I can't define hard height values, which is how you've done it..